# Matrix mirroring/transformation in Python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, transformation

I'm looking for a Python function which, given the 2d array A, will output B:

```
A = [[a, b, c],
     [d, e, f],
     [g, h, i]]

B = [[a, d, g],
     [b, e, h],
     [c, f, i]]
```

i.e. the first row becomes the first column, the second row becomes the second column etc.

Thanks.

Comment: What, **exactly** do you mean by a 2d array? Do you have a list of lists? A `numpy.ndarray`? The appropriate answer will depend on what you are actually working with, and in either case, is probably a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
>>> A = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [4,5,6],
              [7,8,9]])

>>> [list(i) for i in zip(*A)]

[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]] #output
```

Comment: You are using `zip(*A)` in your answer. Where have you defined `A`? That's what I am saying

Answer (score 1):

```
A = [[a, b, c],
     [d, e, f],
     [g, h, i]]

B = zip(*A)
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the matrix transpose. Here is an example

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [4,5,6],
              [7,8,9]])
B = A.T

# array([[1, 4, 7],
#        [2, 5, 8],
#        [3, 6, 9]])
```